# View передает пустой объект в controller. Asp core

Tags: mvc, asp.net-core

Пытаюсь сделать метод обновления данных,передаю через Get запрос во View объект,View его нормально принимает ,но после заполнения формы почему-то возвращает в Post пустой объект.
                **GET запрос**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int? id)
        {
            if (id != null)
            {
                err error = await db.Errors.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.id == id);
                var hstr = db.ErHstr.Where(p => p.errid == id);
                editClass ed = new editClass
                {
                    Err = error,
                    ErHs = hstr.ToArray()
                };

                return View(ed);
            }
            return NotFound();
        }
```

**Post запрос**,  показывающий какой объект получен

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(editClass ed)
        {

            ed.ToString();
            return NotFound(ed);
         }
```

**Сама вьюшка**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Update";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@model TestApp.ViewModels.editClass
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Редактирование ошибки";
}

<h3>@Model.Err.id</h3>
<form asp-action="Update" asp-controller="err" asp-route-id="@Model.Err.id">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Err.status" class="control-label">Статус</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="Err.status" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Err.buf" class="control-label">Комментарий</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="Err.buf" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**Модель**

```
  namespace TestApp.ViewModels
    {
        public class editClass
        {
            public err Err { get; set; }
            public ErrorHistory[] ErHs { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

View нормально получает объект из Get запроса,но обратно передает пустой объект
 что-то типо этого

```
{"err":{"id":0,"date":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","s_descript":null,"f_descript":null,"status":"Решенная1","criticality":null,"urgency":null,"buf":"2","history":null,"user_id":null},"erHs":null}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашей форме у вас есть инпуты только для этих полей

```
asp-for="Err.status", asp-for="Err.buf"
```

И при их заполнении они правильно возвращаются, заметьте объект не пустой, пустые только те поля которые вы не задали.

```
"status":"Решенная1"
"buf":"2"
```

То есть у вас работает всё как вы запрограммировали и предполагается системой.

Ваш объект в `Update(editClass ed)` создаётся `ASP.NET Core 2.0` на основе переданных параметров, параметры которые из `View` не передаются в объект не попадут.

Правильное решение, это сначала получить объект из базы, и потом обновить именно те поля, которые есть в форме.

Для этого во вьюшке мы добавляем скрытое поле с `Id`

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Err.Id" class="form-control" />
```

В контроллере на основе `Id` из вьюшки мы получим объект из базы данных и перезапишем в нём необходимые значения.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Update(editClass ed)
 {
    editClass ed1 = await db.Errors.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.id == ed.id);
    ed1.buf = ed.err.buff;
    ed1.status= ed.err.status;
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
 }
```

Добавлю что классы лучше всего наименовать в C# в UpperCamelCase и давать полные названия полям без сокращений.